# Stop os.walk going down further at a specific directory name

Tags: python

I need to stop os.walk from going down further if the path contains both "release" and "arm-linux". I have a bunch of these at different levels of directories. So I can't simply dictate the level. So far I have the following and it unnecessarily dive past directories in 'arm-linux'.

```
def main(argv):
        for root, dirs, files in os.walk("."):
                path = root.split(os.sep)
                if "release" and "arm-linux" in path:
                        print(os.path.abspath(root))
                        getSharedLib(argv)
```

[**update**] This is my solution

```
def main(argv):
        for root, dirs, files in os.walk("."):
                path = root.split(os.sep)
                if "release" in path and "arm-linux" in path:
                        print(os.path.abspath(root))
                        getSharedLib(argv)
                        del dirs[:]
```

Comment: Incidentally, `"release" and "arm-linux" in path` doesn't do what you think it does.  It is parsed as `(("release") and ("arm-linux" in path))`,  you need `"release" in path and "arm-linux" in path`

Comment: When your condition is met, remove all items from `dirs`.

Comment: @MartinBonner Ty. I definitely need to program more...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html)

> When *topdown* is True, the caller can modify the *dirnames* list in-place (perhaps using `del` or slice assignment), and `walk()` will only recurse into the subdirectories whose names remain in *dirnames*;

Note that *topdown* is True by default.

---

**Edit**

To delete all the elements of `dirs`, you will need something like `del dirs[:]`.  That will delete all the elements of the list object that is referred to as `dirs` in your code, but is referred to by another name in the `os.walk` code.

Just using `del dirs` will stop `dirs` in your code from referring to the list, but won't do anything to the `os.walk` reference.  Similarly `dirs = []` will replace what `dirs` in your code refers to, but won't affect `os.walk` code.

Comment: Wonderful. I just needed del dirs[:]. Ty.

Comment: why does `del dirs[:]` do the job but `del dirs` does not ?

Comment: @dafnahaktana I have edited in an explanation.  If that is not sufficiently clear, I suggest you ask a separate question.